# How to save the array field in database

Tags: javascript, mysql

here **producerId** value [3,5], and i want to save in database like { "id" :"1","userId" :"3"},{"id":"2","userId":"5"}

```
  const Ids =  _.map(req.body.producerId, (user) => ({
    const projectList =  await ProjectTeam.create({
      userId: user,
      });
      return res.json({
        success: true,
        message: 'added successfully! ',
      });
```

Comment: *"i don't know what is wrong here"* We also don't know what is wrong... Do you get a console error? What is your issue and your question? What is `ProjectTeam` ? Are you using underscore.js or what is that variable `_` ? Your question lacks details and clarity

Comment: want to save in  this format { "id" :"1","userId" :"3"},{"id":"2","userId":"5"} in my database, ProjectTeam is tablename

Comment: yes, I know what format you want to save, you already typed it in the question, but the others questions I made? [edit] your question, let it clear and add details

Comment: I don't know what is wrong here either. What happens when you run this?

Answer (score 1):

multiple insert at the database with a loop it's a bad idea because it's multiple request to database.

i suggest you to organise your objects  and insert all in one rquest like :

```
var ids = req.body.producerId;
var users = [];
for(let i = 0; i<ids.length ;i++){
    users.push({
    userId: ids[i],
  })
}

ProjectTeam.bulkCreate([
  users
]).then(()=>{
  return res.json({
    success: true,
    message: 'added successfully! ',
  });
});
```

for you problems check if req.body.producerId it's not empty

Comment: you can check https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#creating-in-bulk

Comment: Could also do `const users = req.body.producerId.map((userId, index) => ({id: index, userId}))`

Comment: its not inserting in to database ,in console log  `[ { userId: '3' }, { userId: ',' }, { userId: '5' } ]`  the comma field also adding

Comment: @sonam your probleme that a coma exist in the array , so you can add in the loop a condition like `if ( ids[i] != "," )`  or  you can do somthing like `ids = req.body.producerId.filter(a => a !== ',')`